# KDE applications in standard Ubuntu 20.04 do not support accents

Tags: gnome, keyboard, kde

KDE applications like KWordQuiz do not recognize accents in Portuguese typed by the combination of two keys (like é, ã, ó) using either US International Keyboard or ABNT. The accent characters (', ~, `) do not even show up when their keys are pressed twice. This works well, on the other hand, with Gnome applications.

Is there any package that should be installed in a standard Ubuntu 20.04 setup in order to solve this issue?

Comment: I installed KWordQuiz, Okular and other KDE programs on the top of a standard Ubuntu using the Ubuntu Software Application. By default, the snap versions of these programs were installed and I realized now that they do not support accents. Their deb versions (from Ubuntu's repository) do work well, although they are older.